# If/else statement only works as intended with integers.

Tags: c, scanf

It works fine until you put in a character, then it becomes an infinite loop, as opposed to just saying "invalid number". I don't understand why. Please help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
int i = 0;
int number;
while (i == 0){
        printf("Enter a number greater than 0 and smaller than 23.\n");
        scanf (" %d", &number);
        if (number < 23 && number > 0 ){
            printf("Sucess!\n");
            break;
        } else {
            printf("Invalid number.\n");
}
}
}
```

Comment: Why don't you show us the code that didn't work?  Don't make us guess what you did when using a `char`.

Comment: `scanf` doesn't consume input that doesn't match, so the letter stays on the input. Check the return value from `scanf` to see if it succeeded.

Comment: Check by checking the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: Aside: `while (i == 0)` is an infinite loop anyway.

Comment: @WeatherVane there's a `break` hidden in there

Comment: @ChristianGibbons oh OK thanks myblind.

Comment: Another aside: `int number;` is *uninitialised*, so when a letter is typed the test may accidentally pass.

Comment: Apart from checking the return value from `scanf` I suggest adding `while(getchar() != '\n');` into the `else` block, to clear out the input buffer.

Comment: So I printed the "number" variable after putting in 'r' and it printed 0. But I still don't understand why it became an infinite loop as opposed to just printing "success!". Also, how can I fix this? How can I make it print invalid number when the user puts in a character? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were several suggestions to improve your code:

- Always check the return value from `scanf`, which tells you how many
  inputs were successfully read.
- Unprocessed input remains in the input buffer - and has to be cleared
  out.
- Uninitialised variables can mislead you.
- Make use of the `i` variable which controls the loop.

Amended with comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int number = 0;                                 // an invalid value
    while (i == 0) {
        printf("Enter a number greater than 0 and smaller than 23.\n");
        if(scanf("%d", &number) == 1 && number < 23 && number > 0 ) {
            printf("Success!\n");
            i = 1;                                  // satisfy the loop control
        } else {
            printf("Invalid number.\n");
            while(getchar() != '\n');               // clear the input buffer
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I "check the return value from `scanf`? I don't really know what that means.

Comment: I did that in the `if` conditions. `scanf` will return `1` if there was one format specifer, which successfully converted the input. When you enter `'a'` it will not be converted to `int`, so `scanf` will return `0`, and the `'a'` remains in the input buffer. That is why your code went into infinite loop - the input is continuously refused.

Comment: I think I get it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, the entered value is out of the checked span 0 to 23. What you get when enter a character puts some very bad value in your int variable width. Why? Because the scanf function takes the input as a decimal number, so it reads more than a character, and whatever is in memory around, gets picked as a number. I hope that his helps.
This is a commonly encountered problem, please look into the usage of scanf here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/